# Bluetooth is Broken, Is there a way to reinstall it from scratch?

Tags: networking, permissions, bluetooth, directory

I am using  Dell Inspiron 3501 running Ubuntu 20.04.  In an effort to install blueman I have installed and reinstalled several packages.  Well I got to the point where bluetooth has failed fatally with the following errors:

`$ systemctl status bluetooth`

Bluetooth management interface 1.18 initialized
 bluetoothd[910]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.45 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
bluetoothd[910]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.45 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
bluetoothd[910]: connect error: Permission denied (13)
bluetoothd[910]: connect error: Too many levels of symbolic links (40)
bluetoothd[910]: connect error: Too many levels of symbolic links (40)
bluetoothd[910]: connect error: Permission denied (13)
bluetoothd[910]: connect error: Device or resource busy (16)
bluetoothd[910]: connect error: Too many levels of symbolic links (40)
bluetoothd[910]: connect error: Too many levels of symbolic links (40)

I just finished doing a timeshift restore hoping that would fix my issue and it did not.  I just restarted the bluetooth service and now I am getting the following errors:
systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
bluetoothd[19985]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
bluetoothd[19985]: Starting SDP server
bluetoothd[19985]: Bluetooth management interface 1.18 initialized
bluetoothd[19985]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
bluetoothd[19985]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.45 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
bluetoothd[19985]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.45 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
bluetoothd[19985]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)

I just ran:
`$ lsmod | grep -i blu`

bluetooth             630784  41 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth

`$ rfkill list all`

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no

Comment: Please start with OS & release details.

Comment: You usually need to add `sudo` before any `systemctl` commands.

Comment: well I didn't need to use sudo for this, I am not sure if have ever used sudo for this command on my machine

Comment: What is the output of `lsmod | grep -i blu` please? Edit your question and add it to the bottom.

Comment: @darth_epoxy I have posted the command and the output in the question.

Comment: @Nmath - I noticed in my history I was using `sudo systemctl` the entire time I had this pc.  I didn't have to use `sudo` anymore after I did a restore with timeshift in an attempt to fix bluetooth.   I did something there just not sure what

Answer (score 1):

So it seems to be fixed:

`$ sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth`

I was able to connect to my headset and it works!!!

I also was able to transfer files from my wife's laptop.  Whoo HOO!!!